# Writing multiple files into one file using Python, while taking input from the user to choose the files to scan

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so I have code that looks like this:

```
input_name="PLACEHOLDER"

while input_name != "":
    input_name=input('Part Name: ')


with open("/pathway/%s.txt" %input_name ,"r") as read_data, open("output.txt","w") as output:

if part_name != "":
    f=input_data.read() 
    print(input_data)

    output.write(part_name)
    output.write(date)
    output.write(y)
else:
    read_data.close()   
    output.close()
```

I know it looks a little broken, but what I need to do is fix the loop, because I need to be able to take multiple inputs, and write each of those inputs(file names) to the same file at the end of the program. I probably need at least one more loop in here, I'm just looking for ideas or a kick in the right direction. I have other formatting code in there, this is just the bare bones, looking for an idea on what kind of loops I could run. Thanks to anyone who takes the time to look at this for me!

Comment: @user357269 where do you see the infinite loop?

Comment: It doesn't make an infinite loop, the problem is that I need a suggestion on where to move my loops, because after I enter "x" number of file names, the while loop ends, but the program doesn't have a file_name to grab for the rest of the program.

Comment: @ChaseGarfield I'll try to get you started on the right track. Give me a few to type up some pseduo code.

Comment: Use `argparse` instead of your endless `input`

Comment: indentation is indeed off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going to mockup some code for you to help guide you, no guarantees this will work to any degree, but should get you started.

First off, lets store all the part names in a list so we can loop over them later on:

```
input_name = []
user_input = input('Part Name: ')
while user_input != "":
    input_name.append(user_input)
    user_input = input('Part Name: ')
```

Now let's loop through all the files that we just got:

```
for (file_name in input_name):
    with open("/pathway/%s.txt" %file_name ,"r") as read_data, open("output.txt","w") as output:
        # any thing file related here
        print(input_data)
        output.write(part_name)
        output.write(date)
        output.write(y)
print("All done")
```

That way you get all the user input at once, and process all the data at once.

Comment: This is a great push in the right direction! The program keeps overwriting on the write function so there is only one set of data in the file output. But thank you for a good start!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the `output.txt` open from the beginning of the execution and open each file after the user input its name.

Example (not tested):

```
with open("output.txt","w") as output:

    while True:
        input_name = input('Part Name: ').strip()

        if input_name == '':
            break

        with open("/pathway/%s.txt" %input_name ,"r") as read_data:

            if part_name != "":
                output.write(read_data.read())
```

Remember that you don't need to close the file if you open it in `with`

Comment: `for name in iter(lambda:input(prompt).strip(),''):` ... but thats really probably too advanced

Comment: @JoranBeasley I agree, Python is a beautiful language but it takes time to learn all the features

Comment: Yeah, as a recent python learner, I'm discovering this all too often.

Comment: Most of these features come from functional programming, which can change the way we code in the future